# Adding a Facebook share button on a recycleview

Tags: java, android, facebook-share

I have added a share button on my layout file and made a clickListeneter for it but still don't know what to do!

```
@Override
  protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
     viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
     viewHolder.setPostImageUrl(model.getPostImageUrl());
     viewHolder.btnShare.setOnClickListener(new 
     View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
             ..... 
           }
         });
  }
```

---

I updated my code i just need the the image URL, how to get it from recycleview

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  String pathOfBmp = ..... ;
  Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(pathOfBmp);
  Intent sharingIntent = new 
  Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
  sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,bitmapUri);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

Comment: Set the onClick when you initialise the view in your viewholder.

Comment: I did already 
btnShare = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);

Comment: What exactly happening ? OnClick not getting trigger ? Getting any exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you need to share text on Facebook, you can do the following:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

This will show a dialog that allows you to select whatever app you want to share on.

Comment: Your answer is useful, but i want to share the imageview this code works with text only

Comment: You can't share a view, you can share a link or text

Comment: I'm using firebase so i would share an image Link

Comment: @AmeniKerkeni You can share image too. But for that you need to use `URI` and get path from it with `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM`